# Zoom in/out issue in webview in Android

Tags: android, webview, zooming

I am displaying the image in webview.
By using this:

```
final String mimeType = "text/html";
        final String encoding = "utf-8";
        String filePath = "file://"+file;
        final String html = "<img width=\"100%\" height=\"100%\" src=\""+filePath+"\" />";
        Log.v("HTML",html);
        webViewe.loadDataWithBaseURL("fake://not/needed", html, mimeType, encoding, "");
```

When double click on the WebView its zoom the image but when again i double click on it the blank white screen is display.
How to resolve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean you need zoom controls:

```
 webview.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
```

Comment: I have added this. After adding this, when i double click its get zoom, but again when i double click it shows a blank screen (Webview). I think it is unable to go back in previous stat

Comment: If you use the zoom controls instead of double clicking does the same thing happen?

Comment: You must be doing something that your not showing in your question

Comment: @Blundell can you tell me how to zoom the webview centrally?

Comment: The zoom on webview is user dependant. I believe you would have to write some javascript to keep your webview centered when zooming, but this goes against 'what is expected' when a user uses your app and is not recommended.

Comment: Still does not working Blundell my code is below  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14497943/zoom-in-out-in-webview-android